# In Java, is it required to synchronize write access to an array if each thread writes to a separate cell space?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

Is it required to synchronize write access to an array in Java if each thread writes to a separate cell space?

**EDIT:** Specifically, the array is either a primitive Array or an immutable object array. Ex. An int array or a String array.

Comment: The question seems fairly specific, though the type of the array may be relevant.  If it's an array of objects, clarify whether you mean overwriting the reference (`array[1] = new Foo(bar)`), or mutating the object (`array[1].setBar(bar)`).  @sthupahsmaht, your comment is more general.

Comment: +1 to Matthew on the specificity of the question: this is a well-defined question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java array thread-safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132507/java-array-thread-safety)

Comment: No it is not. In the other question, threads didn't have separate cell space.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, synchronization is not needed.

It is defined in [JLS §17.6 Word Tearing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6):

> One implementation consideration for Java virtual machines is that every field and array element is considered distinct; updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element. In particular, two threads that update adjacent elements of a byte array separately must not interfere or interact and do not need synchronization to ensure sequential consistency.

Comment: Nice, this should imply inefficient operations on arrays on some architectures, among other things

Comment: That's not what your reference says: there are certain operations that aren't subject to data races, but that's not all Array operations.

Comment: @Charlie: "every field and array element is considered distinct; updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element.". This means that array[1] and array[2] can be considered as two completely independent variables, so I think this answers OP's question

Comment: @akappa I'm not an architecture expert.  However, word tearing was recently discussed on the GCC mailing list on a discussion of the C++0x memory model, and this post was encouraging: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.patches/232708

Comment: @bkail: so it seems that the aforementioned set of architectures is actually empty if we limit ourselves to non-ancient processors... good to know :)

Comment: @bkail: I still maintain you cannot safely manipulate `long` or `double` values without synchronization

Comment: @Jen See my response in your answer.  This is akin to "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?".  If all threads are operating independently on their own cell, it does not matter if a thread gets pre-empted mid-write so long as the reader guarantees that the write finishes prior to using the cell (e.g., by using .join() on the writing thread).  I'll admit that .join() is a form of synchronization.

Comment: Oracle broke the link to the document. Here is a new link: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6)

Answer (score 5):

If read access is also partitioned in the same manner, then synchronization is not needed as per bkail's link.

But if the threads *read* each other's writes, it would still be necessary to have a [memory barrier](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) to force synchronization of cache contents. Otherwise, threadys may get inconsistent read results.

Answer (score 3):

Not a simple *yes or no* issue. Some things to consider:

- Your question implies that you are storing primitive types (or references) in your array. Performing complex operations on objects stored in the array may require synchronization.
- Changing `long` or `double` values is **not safe** without synchronization
- Even if you are storing primitives that are *not* `double` or `long`, there is the possibility of another threads not being able to see changed values immediately because of caching (resulting in *stale reads*)

Comment: The first point is true, the second is not.  It's true that changing long/double is not _atomic_, but that's irrelevant if the value is only be read by one thread.

Comment: @bkail: Are you sure? What if the writing thread writes one 32-bit word of a `long` when it is interrupted? The reading thread would then read a corrupted value, no?

Comment: If multiple threads are involved with a single cell, then I agree that synchronization is required, but that wasn't the problem statement.

Comment: No, bkail is wrong. Jen is right. 64 bit words on 32 bit machines can be written half and then the thread gets interrupted and the data is inconsistent.

Comment: @Angel I do not dispute that the data is inconsistent.  I claim it does not matter if no one reads it.  In other words, if the original poster is saying, "from the main thread, spawn 10 threads, join them all, and then view the results; from each thread, write to a unique cell", then it simply doesn't matter if a thread gets interrupted "mid-write" because no one will see the intermediate value.

Comment: Yes, if every thread writes only to specific cells *and* the array is not resized (it is a Java array, not a collection class), then there is no thread synchronization issue at all.

Comment: @bkail sorry I don't get it? Why would one program with multiple threads to synchronize them in such an extraordinary way? I would say your answer only confuses people that are asking stuff here, making it very difficult for them to learn anything. Look at the original question ... if that guy stores longs in the array and has reading threads he needs to synchronize writing and reading.

Comment: I think bkail's point is that because the threads act on different sections of the array, it's as if they are working with separate objects -- i.e., no thread contention.

Comment: @Angel A program that wants to read an unknown amount of data, process it in parallel, and aggregate the result at the end.  Having each thread operate on its own cell seems useful.  If I understand correctly, you are doubtful that the original poster understood the question he actually asked.  I assume he did based on the phrasing of the question, so I gave a straightforward answer.  You assume he did not and believe we should give him alternatives instead.  It's hard to say which approach is better.

Comment: @bkail and? why do you give this overcomplicated awnser when it clearly don't fit to the question and is only confusing newbies? (The question was not about spawning 10 threads and joining them later, it was about concurrent write access)

Comment: @Angel I give a simple answer to a simple question: concurrent write accesses to separate array cells are safe per the JVM spec.  I assume based on the phrasing of the question that the original poster is not a newbie.

Comment: @bkail: Oh, lol. And I assumed on the phrasing of his question *and* your answer that you both where newbies, my fault then. Sorry for the confusion I may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

You typically need to synchronize if you want other threads to be able to always see the last value you've written.  But I could some cases where you'd be, say, precomputing a giganticly expensive *long[]* (where each entry would take a lot of CPU) and you'd be doing that from several threads, knowing no two of these threads shall write to the same cell.  Then once all your threads would be done you'd be using synchronization once to be sure each subsequent read would see the correct values.  Something like that.

Note that if you don't want to deal yourself with synchronization issues you may want to look into classes like *AtomicLongArray*.  As an added benefit, classes like *AtomicLongArray* may be backed by an implementation that is impossible to re-create in 100% Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are asking, updating what each index holds, **but you are not guaranteed** that other threads reading the data in the indexes are seeing current data.

There is a keyword in Java called `volatile` that marks instance and class variables so that they JVM knows these values are expected to change and to not do any read cache optimization **because the reading threads may get stale data**. Since you can't mark array index contents `volatile` other readers can get stale data.

Using raw `Arrays` in Java is only good practice in very specific scenarios. Yours might be one of those cases, but I can't tell from the question, therefore I suggest you look at [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) specifically at [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) if you don't want duplicates.

These are part of the standard library for a reason now, and if you are doing heavy threading and data sharing you should be as intimately familiar with `java.util.concurrent` as possible.

Comment: Who downvoted this? And why? As far as I can tell Jarrod is right here.

Answer (score 1):

Are the same threads also reading the value.  If so then you are ok.  If not then you need to worry about whether other threads see the most recent values.   This is usually taken care of through the key work volatile or through atomics variables.

```
For example if you have an int [] intArray with three elements.

thread 1 updates intArray[0]=<new value>
thread 2 updates intArray[1]=<new value>
thread 3 updates intArray[2]=<new value>
```

if these threads also are used to read the values then you are ok but if a new thread --> thread 4 attempts to read the values then there is no guarantee that it will see the latest assignment.

you'll be ok if you use AtomicIntegerArray, AtomicLongArray, or AtomicReferenceArray

Comment: Again someone had downvoted it without giving a comment, I don'T find that approbriated and upvoted it again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question posed to the Concurrency Interest mailing list - "[Atomic byte[] operations?](http://markmail.org/thread/4sd7ogs5j2yyat7n#query%3a+page:1+mid%3afagiv5sddtdfthfy+state%3aresults)".

David Holmes said:

> Reading/writing different regions of the array should act like
>   accessing independent arrays. This is what "no word-tearing"
>   guarantees. No matter how the array is implemented by the VM the VM
>   has to make sure this holds for basic array accesses.
>
> As I said it is less clear if a native version of arraycopy gets
>   involved.

Comment: Another discussion worth reading - http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Concurrent-copy-to-array-td8911.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't write directly to a shared resource. Your gonna make the multi thread program perform worse than its single thread counter part. Trashing effect in Cache as Cache is fetched and invalidated in blocks. Do look at this talk if you want to know more. Use volatile and Synchronize its better than using nothing but still slow.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCattsfHR4o
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to add a Question with this topic. I made a test that force contention while accessing an array. Both controlling coordinated access or with a non-synchronized read-modify-write operation like index--.

When using index-- some counters are > 1 (all should be 1, otherwise the mutual exclusion broke)

```
public class App {


static int threads = 1000;
static int maxIndex = 1000;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        testThreads();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return;

}

public static void testThreads() throws InterruptedException {

    AtomicInteger[] ids = new AtomicInteger[maxIndex];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
        ids[i] = new AtomicInteger(0);  
    }
    Executor exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(maxIndex);
    final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startGate.await();
                    try {
                        int i = maxIndex;
                        while (i > 0) {
                            /** 
                             * Interchanging this lines force or avoid collisions. 
                             */
                         // i = --maxIndex;
                            i = index.decrementAndGet();
                            ids[i].incrementAndGet(); 
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ignored) {
                        System.out.println(ignored);
                    } finally {
                        endGate.countDown();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
    startGate.countDown();
    endGate.await();
    System.out.println(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(ids)));
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In general, yes.  Try Vector instead.

Comment: `Vector` is for all practical purposes **deprecated** there are better alternatives in the `java.util.concurrent` package. Any advice to use `Vector` or `Hashtable` is poor advice.

Comment: @Charlie Martin: 36K rep and suggesting a class from the past?  Did the nineties called saying they want their inneficient, lame, classes back or what!?  ;)

Comment: Snore.  Yes, let's use the new complicated classes when a simple old class works fine.  And get off my lawn.

Comment: A class that is @deprecated should not be suggested ;D In non threaded environments java.util.ArrayList is significantly faster ...

Comment: I agree.  However, since Vector is NOT deprecated (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html and notice that Jarrod says "for all practical purposes", which translates to "but I don't like it") your advice is misplaced.

Comment: "It's not what we don't know that hurts us; it's what we think we know that ain't so."-- Will Rogers