# is String Array thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is bookTokens thread- safe in below code ? I am not pretty sure if values of String array can be read in thread-safe manner ?

```
public Class Myclass{

    private static final String[] bookTokens = { "amazon", "manning", "book"};

    public static void methodOne(){
    //read values from bookTokens
    }


    public static void methodTwo(){
    //read values from bookTokens
    }
```

}

Comment: String is immutable therefore they are thread safe, except for StringBuilder

Comment: Arrays are not immutable. But if you're only reading, not writing, then it's thread-safe.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132507/java-array-thread-safety)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  For instance, the example in the other Question involves mutating the array.

Comment: Consider using [unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) to ensure immutability and thread-safety.

Comment: I would have used Guava's immutable list, but don't want to overkill if above code is inherently thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an array is not thread-safe.

However, in this case we have an array that will not be updated, and that is initialized in a way that ensures proper synchronization with any thread that subsequently reads it.

Therefore, in this case, the code is thread-safe.

Comment: "...and is initialized in a way that ensures proper synchronization..."  Yes.  See my response to eitanfar, below, for a reference to a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This code is only thread safe if you can ensure that there is no code in Myclass that does the equivalent of:

```
    public static void mutateBookTokens() {
        bookTokens[2] = "addison-wesley";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any code that only reads values and does not change anything is by nature thread safe, since the data it uses is used as if it was immutable.

Comment: See _Java Concurrency in Practice_ by Brian Goetz et al., section 3.5. (Safe Publication), and section 3.5.4 (Effectively Immutable Objects).  A technically mutable object (e.g., the array in the example above) that the program never modifies is called _effectively immutable_.  Use of an effectively immutable object is thread safe _iff_ the object was _safely published_.  The array in the example is safely published because it was published via. a `final` field _after_ it was fully initialized.

Comment: +1 for effectively immutable object reference. Thanks