# Is Android SDK's CircularArray thread safe?

Tags: android, concurrency, thread-safety, circular-buffer

This question is in regard to [android.support.v4.util.CircularArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/CircularArray.html).

I'm looking at using a `CircularArray` to feed data from one thread to another. Each element is an array of type `short[]`.

- Can the Array be safely added to and popped from, concurrently?
- Can I be sure that when I try to pop an element, that it has been atomically added to the array?
- Can I safely clear the Array from a particular thread?

The documentation for `CircularArray` doesn't say anything about thread-safety, but I'm wondering if there are general assumptions specified elsewhere in the SDK documentation that apply to it.

Comment: This will help you understand the difference about "thread safe" and "access" the data of an array. In short, the arrays are thread safe but you have no guarantee that what you read is the "latest" value set in the array.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132507/java-array-thread-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not explicitly stated, the classes of the Android platform are not thread-safe. So the answer to your questions is **no**.

You better use a queue from the [java.util.concurrent](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package to implement your inter-thread communication.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is what I'm looking for.