# Java thread safety

Tags: java

```
public void doSomething(){

    Object[] a = new Object[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) a[i] = executorService.submit(callable[i]).get();

}
```

Is this thread safe or not?

Thanks

Comment: `a` is only accessed by one thread.

Comment: Why do you say `a` is being accessed by two threads?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn @Joni executorService is spawning new thread, no? total 5 threads here accessing `a`

Comment: No, `get` will block, and then your thread assigns the result in the `a` array.

Comment: What is `callable[i]`? For now none of those new threads is shown to be using `a`, nor `a[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

The code, as shown, does not contain any thread-unsafe behavior.

The *evaluation* of the expression `callable[i]` occurs in the main thread, and the *assignment* of the result of `get` to `a[i]` also occurs on the main thread. You also get happens-before relationships helping with consistency: the call to `submit` on the main thread happens-before any thread tasks, which happen-before the call to `get` returns.

Of course, whatever actions `callable[i]` itself performs must be done in a thread-safe manner, and furthermore this does not actually enable parallelism because you block the main thread waiting for each subtask before starting the next one.

**Edit:** You don't have an issue of conflicting writes in your edited code since every task accesses a different array index. The [visibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132602/1424875) outlined here shouldn't be an issue as (IIRC) the act of `get()`ing the result implies a memory barrier which makes the writes visible.

Comment: You may want to add that `get` is for sure thread safe: ["Memory consistency effects: Actions taken by the asynchronous computation happen-before actions following the corresponding Future.get() in another thread."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR - Yes it is thread-safe.

The array in `a` is thread confined:

- The variable `a` is declared as a local variable, and no other thread can possibly see it<sup>1</sup>.
- You are not "publishing" the value in `a` to any other thread.

Therefore the state of the array or the variable are not relevant to thread safety.

Likewise, `i` is thread confined and not relevant.

There is a *happens-before* relationship between the call to submit and the thread that executes the task that ensures that `callable[i]`' s state is fully visible to the callable's `call` method when it runs.

The values that you are assigning into `a` are the result of calling `get()` on a `Future`.  The `Future.get()` method is thread-safe.  It ensures that there is a *happens-before* relationship between the thread that populated the `Future` and the thread that calls `get()`.

This all adds up to "thread safe".

---

<sup>1 - Another thread calling `doSomething()` will have a different instance of the `a` variable and it will contain a different `Object[]`.</sup>

---

The only *possible* concerns are:

- Is the `callables` array safely published to this thread?  (In the event that it was created by or populated by some other thread.)  If not, then stale data may be used.
- Are the `Callable` instances in the `callables` array thread-safe ... or effectively thread confined?

But these things are not really the "concern" of this code ... and cannot be addressed in this code.

---

There is one other thing to say about this example.  This the following statement is actually completely synchronous.

```
a[i] = executorService.submit(callable[i]).get();
```

What it does is to submit a task to the executor and then wait (blocking the current thread!) until the task has finished.  As a result, your 5 tasks will run one after another ... not in parallel

If you are trying to get some parallelism, then you should do something like this:

```
Object[] a = new Object[5];
Future<Object>[] f = new Future<>[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    f[i] = executorService.submit(callable[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a[i] = f[i].get();
}
```

If you are not trying to get parallelism, then this is better in almost all use-cases<sup>2</sup>:

```
Object[] a = new Object[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a[i] = callable[i].call();
}
```

---

<sup>2 - One case where it would be incorrect is if you were using a bounded executor service as a way of preventing resource utilization by a certain class of "intensive" tasks from swamping other things.</sup>

Comment: No it can't.  `a` is a >>local variable<< declared in this method.  It is not visible outside of this specific method call.  There is no possibility that any other thread could see it.